# ¿Como refrescar la fila de una tabla cuando se actualiza por Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax, datatables

Tengo el siguiente script de Jquery con ajax

```js
$('#btn_cofr_update').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form =$('#form_upd_requi');
    var action=form.attr('action');
    var id=$('#id_').val();

     var data=$('#form_upd_requi').serialize();
     var url=$(this).attr('href');

     $.ajax({
       type:'PUT',
       url:'/admin/requirements/'+id,
       data:data,
       success:function(data){
         console.log(data);
       },
       error:function(data){
         console.log('mal');
       }
     });
     
  });
```

Funciona bien, pero para que actualice la vista me toca recargar la página quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que me actualice la tabla sin recargar toda la página Muchas Graciass

Answer (score 1):

usa tuTabla.ajax.reload(); una vez hayas recibido respuesta del ajax de modificación.

Te dejo la documentación: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#btn_cofr_update').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form =$('#form_upd_requi');
    var action=form.attr('action');
    var id=$('#id_').val();

     var data=$('#form_upd_requi').serialize();
     var url=$(this).attr('href');

     $.ajax({
       type:'PUT',
       url:'/admin/requirements/'+id,
       data:data,
       success:function(data){
         $("#form_upd_requi").load(location.href+" #form_upd_requi>*","");
       },
       error:function(data){
         console.log('mal');
       }
     });
     
  });
```

Comment: Me función bien pero ahora, como lo estoy haciendo con modals el primer registro me actualiza bien pero cuando abro el modal de editar de otro registro me esta tomando en el valor de input del primer registro que ya había actualizado anteriormente

Comment: Esa es otra cosa, deberías abrir otra pregunta con tu duda. Y para esa necesitaríamos tu código html. Parece ser que ahí siempre estás tomando el valor de la id de $('#id_').val(); y para nosotros ese valor es el mismo (al menos que tú en otro lado le estés cambiando de valor.

Si te sirvió mi respuesta para la pregunta en concreto dala como resulta y pon esta respuesta como la que te sirvió. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Para poder realizar lo que necesitas, puedo sugerirte lo siguiente:

1. Tu función ajax debe recibir una confirmación de que los valores fueron modificados en tu base de datos.
2. Una vez recibida la confirmación, debes actualizar las columnas (1,2,3...n), en la fila correspondiente a tu ID, con los valores que enviaste a la función AJAX.
3. Igualmente puedes reemplazar el contenido del elemento TR, con el html que responda el servidor. Ejemplo de respuesta para reemplazar el contenido de TR seria: "Valor 1, Fila 10Valor 2, Fila 10Valor 3, Fila 10"

He preparado un ejemplo en el siguiente enlace https://jsfiddle.net/ptykamikaze/4f728833/1/